# Where to place the done() call in Jest unit tests on a middleware that logs the request body to the db?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, junit

I am making my own custom middleware that logs the http body to the database

## logger.js

```js
const connect = require('connect');

module.exports = function(db_con){
  const app = connect();
  app.use((req,res,next)=>{
     const sql = `INSERT INTO requests VALUES (:method,:url) returning id`;
     const stmt  = db.prepare(initialInsert);

     const insert_result = initialInsertStmt.run({method:req.method,'url':req.url            });
     req.id = insert_result.lastInsertRowid;
     next();
  });
  app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    var body = [];
    
    req.on('data',(data)=> body.push(data));

    req.on('end',() => {
       body = body.toString();

       const sql = `UPDATE requests SET body=:body) where id=:id`;
       const stmt  = db.prepare(initialInsert);

       const insert_result = initialInsertStmt.run({'body':body,'id':req.id});
       next();
  });
}
```

And I use it like this:

```js
  const connect = require('connect');
  const logger = require('./logger.js');
  const sqlite3 = require('better-sqlite3');

  const app = connect();

  app.use(logger(sqlite3('./access_log.sqlite')));
  app.use((req,res,next)=> res.end('hello'));

  app.listen(8080);
```

And I want to test the `logger.js` functionality:

```
const logger = require('./logger.js');
const request = require('supertest');
  const sqlite3 = require('better-sqlite3');
  test('post Is logged into DB',(done)=>{
  const db = sqlite3(':memory:');
  const app = connect();
  app.use(logger(db));
  app.use((req,res,next())=>{
    expect(req.id).notToBe(null);
    
    const sql = `SElECT * from requests where id=:id`
    const result = db.prepare(sql);
    // Do assertions here
  });
  app.use((req,res)=>res.end("hello"));

  request(app)
        .post('/example?param1=11&param2=22')
        .set('Host','example.com')
        .set('X-MyHeader',3)
        .set("Cookie",  ['c_param1=12345667', 'c_param2=blah'])
        .send("username=techbos&password=Pa%24%24w0rd")
        .then(()=>{});
})
```

The problem is where to place the `done` function. In my case due to asyncronous nature of the logging that I perform I do noy knwo where tests ends. If I place the end in supertest's `request` then function I may not perform all assertions if I place it inside the middleware that performs the assertions in my tests the test may not end.

So how on eathn I can assert that my middleware:

1. Sets the inserted id to `req.id`
2. Saves the request data to the database before sends them out.

Is there a way to manually "mock" the http request perform any event execution manually and then perform the assertions?

## Edit 1

If I place the done here

```
 app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    expect(req.id).notToBe(null);
    
    const sql = `SElECT * from requests where id=:id`
    const result = db.prepare(sql);
    // Do assertions here
    done();
  });
```

The test may end up hanging, besause the following code is still being executed:

```
request(app)
        .post('/example?param1=11&param2=22')
        .set('Host','example.com')
        .set('X-MyHeader',3)
        .set("Cookie",  ['c_param1=12345667', 'c_param2=blah'])
        .send("username=techbos&password=Pa%24%24w0rd")
        .then(()=>{});
```

If I do:

```
request(app)
        .post('/example?param1=11&param2=22')
        .set('Host','example.com')
        .set('X-MyHeader',3)
        .set("Cookie",  ['c_param1=12345667', 'c_param2=blah'])
        .send("username=techbos&password=Pa%24%24w0rd")
        .then(()=>{ done() });
```

I still leave code executed because the test may end before being executed the:

```
  app.use((req,res)=>res.end("hello"));
```

Comment: Why would your tests not end if you place `done` at the end of the endpoint handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  ...
  app.use((req,res,next)=>{                 // remove parenthesis in `next`
    expect(req.id).notToBe(null);
    
    const sql = `SElECT * from requests where id=:id`
    const result = db.prepare(sql);
    // Do assertions here

    next();                                 // call next
  });
  app.use((req,res)=> {
    res.end("hello"));
    done();                                 // DONE HERE
  }
  request(app)
        .post('/example?param1=11&param2=22')
        .set('Host','example.com')
        .set('X-MyHeader',3)
        .set("Cookie",  ['c_param1=12345667', 'c_param2=blah'])
        .send("username=techbos&password=Pa%24%24w0rd")
        .then(()=>{});
})
```

Since logger ends with `next()`, it will then call your assertions function. Inside of it you should use `next()` at the end, so that it will trigger the next middleware, which is `res.end("hello")`. Since `res.end("hello")` ends without calling next, it should be where `done()` is placed.

`request(app). ... .then(...)` will trigger

1. logger's first middleware
2. logger's second middleware
3. assertions middleware added in test
4. res.end and finish.